# How can I take ownership of a file in c# using takeown or icacls?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cmd

I know there are other posts on the matter but none have presented me with a working solution.
I'm trying to take ownership of files under C:\Windows\Media so I can replace them with my own. Currently I've been trying to do that by running either takeown or icacls in CMD, but neither seem to work. The takeown method actually returns success from CMD but I still get access denied when trying to delete the file. With the icacls method I get "the handle is invalid" and still get access denied.
The program is running as administator fyi.
And also in the icacls method changing Environment.Username to "Administrators" doesn't change anything.
Any help is appreciated!
Here is the code for the takeown method:

```
        string[] soundFiles;
        soundFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Windows/Media", "*.wav");
        //string cmdargs = @"/c takeown /F C:\Windows\Media";
        string shortcmdargs = @"/c takeown /F ";
        //Process.Start("CMD.exe", cmdargs);
        string output = "null";
        foreach(string file in soundFiles)
        {
            try
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = shortcmdargs + @"C:\Windows\Media\" + Path.GetFileName(file);
                p.Start();
                output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                System.IO.File.Delete(file);
                System.IO.File.Copy("neco.wav", file);
                
            }
            catch(Exception exce)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Output: " + output + "\neException: " + exce);
            }
            
        }
```

And here is what I get when running it:
[image: error message]

Here is the code for the icacls method:

```
string[] soundFiles;
        soundFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Windows/Media", "*.wav");
        string cmdargs = @"/c takeown /F C:\Windows\Media";
        string shortcmdargs = @"/c takeown /F ";

        Process.Start("CMD.exe", cmdargs);
        string output = "null";
        foreach(string file in soundFiles)
        {
            try
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c icacls " + @"C:\Windows\Media\" + Path.GetFileName(file) + " /grant " + Environment.UserName + ":(OI)(CI)F /T";
                p.Start();
                output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                System.IO.File.Delete(file);
                System.IO.File.Copy("neco.wav", file);
                
            }
            catch(Exception exce)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Output: " + output + "\neException: " + exce);
            }
            
        }
```

And here is what I get with it:
[image: error message]

Comment: that smells like a CAS (.NET Code Access Security) thing.  i dont know if it helps, buts its an interesting read anyway: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/net-code-access-security-cas/

Comment: look this http://www.mikeobrien.net/blog/taking-ownership-and-setting-admin